Given an infinite amount of time, will every possible combination of matter pop into existence?
Apparently it is true that when the universe is in the state of heat death, quantum fluctuations will eventually produce every combination of matter, no matter how unlikely, given an infinite amount of time.
This is difficult for me to phrase correctly so my apologies, but what physical principle states that the "domain" of these random fluctuations has to "cover" all physical possibilities?
For example, you can roll a six sided dice forever and never roll a seven.
In the same way, just as a contrived counterexample, couldn't the quantum fluctuations just produce, say, electrons forever and would never produce a proton, and thus, could never produce a copy of me?
In a similar vein, if the universe is infinite in size, what's to say that every combination of matter must be out there somewhere? What's guaranteeing that distribution?
For example, you can say: "There is a non zero chance of humans evolving (clearly because we are here) so given a universe that is infinitely large, there are infinite planets with humans".
My counter argument would be: "What physical principle even guarantees that the 'dice are rolled' for the rest of the universe? For example, what if we live in a region of the universe that has matter, and the rest of the infinite space is devoid of matter?" I'm sure my counter argument is incorrect, and I want to know why.

Source for your very first claim? Did you read this in a paper?

Is a "heat death" defined as the state after all black holes have evaporated and the vacuum temperature is very nearly 0 K compared to today's 2.7 K? I don't think it is likely that high energy particles like W-, W+ would be produced all the time purely due to quantum fluctuations at this stage of the universe, said "quantum fluctuations" should be a variable depending on the actual temperature it is?

At close to 0 K, most atomic structures should have coalesced into a BEC / neutron-star like clumps, and who knows whether these would disintegrate further/completely at even colder temperatures $\approx 0 K$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20physics%2C%20the,systems)%2C%20their%20initial%20state.
